# What is the equivalent of the Matlab reshape command in C#? How do I convert a C# 2D float array to a 3D float array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, matlab, binaryfiles

In Matlab I have this

```
2darray = fread(fid, [160 304*304], 'float32');
3darray = reshape(2darray, [160 304 304]);
```

In C# I have this:

```
float[,] 2darray = new float[160, 304 * 304];

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("path")))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 304 * 304; j++)
            2darray[i, j] = reader.ReadSingle();
    }
}
```

From here (in C#), how do I reshape the 2D float array into a 3D float array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can't bring Mohammad to the mountain, bring the mountain to Mohammed.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float[,,] dArray = new float[160, 304, 304];

            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("path")))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 160; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 304; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 304; k++)
                        {
                            dArray[i, j, k] = reader.ReadSingle();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```